# Facebook require_login not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having some trouble with my little facebook application, I keep getting this friggin error, "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::require_login()", now the funny bit is that my exact same code is working for other people, but not for me, here is the code.

```
<?php
require_once( "facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php" );
$api_key = "my_api_key";
$secret = "my_secret_key";

$facebook = new Facebook( $api_key, $secret );
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();

echo "Hello World";
echo "Current logged in as <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" />";
?>
```

As you can see it is a simple hello USER application, but for some reason this REFUSES to work for me, so if anyone can help out that would be great, thanx in advance!

Comment: Check your facebook.php file to see if that method is defined.  Also, are you sure you're using the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I downloaded it again now just to be sure, but it still wont work!

Answer (score 9):

Are you using the [newest version of the PHP sdk](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)?

`Facebook::require_login()` is a method from the old SDK.

The new SDK (published in conjunction with the Graph API) is not backwards compatible.

The notion of requiring a login doesn't even exist anymore - you just obtain the user's ID as such.

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: The weird thing is, I tried that first, and I got a very similar error!

Now it seems to be working though, I'm not getting the error anymore, here is what I am seeing, "Hello World Current logged in as Facebook User", it's not printing the persons name, I am also trying to get his user id, but I am assuming that is also the reason why I am not seeing the name, as it requires the uid to get the users name.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function:

---

```
function appInstance($fbconfig){
    try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession(); 
    $fbme = null;
    // Session based graph API call.
    if ($session) {
      try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          //d($e);    //debug
          'Facebook took too long to respond, try again in a few minutes.';
      }
    }
    return $uid;
    return $fbme;
    return $facebook;
}//end appInstance()
```

---

after you make the call to that function use $fbme to pull whatever info you got from your perms like so `$firstName=$fbme['first_name']` or `$email=$fbme['email']`.

Answer (score 0):

a blatant answer, yet, are you on the web domain that you registered your app for on Facebook.
if you registered xxxyy.com, you can use your app only there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps double check that your domain that is registered with facebook is the same as the dev site you are working on? Probably is, but that one will get you if you don't pay attention. Got me first time around on migration :]