# resolving Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() during facebook authentication

Tags: php, facebook

i am currently working on facebook connect login page for my web page.

but i keep receiving 'call to undefined method' error message at line 24:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

when i remove line 24 everything seems to run smoothly .

ut as i am following a tutorial at http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/facebook-graph-api-connect-with-php-and.html and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/ - its kinda left me stumped!

the error message is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in C:\xampp\htdocs\kite\index.php on line 24
```

please help. many thanks in advance. here is my code:

```
<?php session_start();

    //config
    include "resources/Connections/kite.php";

    //connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
    $con = mysql_connect($hostname_kite, $username_kite, $password_kite) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($database_kite, $con) or die(mysql_error());

    //include out functions file giving us access to the protect() function made earlier
    include "resources/php/functions.php";

    //setup facebook connect
    require 'resources/facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appid_kite,
      'secret' => $secret_kite,
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // Let's see if we have an active session
    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
    ob_start();
    ?>
```

Comment: Check the library you are including. make sure you have the latest version Please see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000166/facebook-require-login-not-working

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but for the record:

> For a fast solution replace all references to `getSession()` with  `getUser()`

Example:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

it should say:

```
$session = $facebook->getUser();
```

ref: [Upgrade to PHP SDK v3.0.0](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you dont wish to edit your code, you might wish to revert to a 2.x sdk.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/zipball/v2.1.2