# getUser() is not working in the Facebook SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

```
$response = $fb->get('/me'); 
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
```

is working and my name is shown. 
If I try to follow an example:

```
//Get the FB UID of the currently logged in user
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Why `get_user()` is not working?

All I get is this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::getUser()

Comment: You should add a little bit more information on how do you use the facebook SDK. Where is the rest of your code? Do you instantiate the $facebook object correctly?

Comment: @sotoz well, `$response = $fb->get('/me');
    $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();` is working and my name is shown. Why get_user() is not working? I am using v5 of SDK by Facebook PHP

Comment: Please refer to this question (you might be using an older FB library): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000166/facebook-require-login-not-working

Comment: I have downloaded it yesterday from the facebook page via the green button. It's up to date. Either the getUser() is no moresupported in Facebook SDK or something else is wrong.

Comment: I am also experience the same problem, Help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use $object->getProperty('email'); to get property of user (in this case email)

Answer (score 0):

I can see fb-userid by using below code in callback php:

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
......
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token    
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
```

which you can format as per the requirement.